# Problems with Z-index problems with Hero? Maybe overflow related?

Tags: html, css, z-index

Here's a codepen of my code, since Stack Overflow doesn't yet allow SCSS: https://codepen.io/thedonquixotic/pen/dWXOby

I am trying to make a section that contains a hero image and an h1.

The containing section has a background gradient. It's z-index is set to 1.

The containing section contains an img and an h1. The img z-index is set to -1 and has in the past properly rendered behind the gradient background.

The h1 has a z-index of 2 and should render above both the image and the gradient.

I had this working but then I added in a JS parallax script. I got it working. The h1 etc was still visible but acting kind of weird so I commented out the JS import to focus on making sure I had my flex box stuff set correctly. Now it's not working at all though!

```css
body div section.hero {
  display: flex !important;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 81vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 195, 113, 0.5), rgba(255, 95, 109, 0.5));
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
body div section.hero div img {
  display: flex !important;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 81vh;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
body div section.hero div.svg-flex {
  position: relative;
  display: flex !important;
  padding: 30px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
body div section.hero div.svg-flex .hero-text {
  width: 95vw;
  top: 30vh;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  font-size: 6rem;
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2.2px;
}
body div section.hero div.svg-flex h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Aller', Arial;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  max-width: 70rem;
  margin: 2vh auto 0;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero scene" id="scene" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="layer" style="display: flex;" data-depth="0.40"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/32/93/21/329321959fcaf0d24e2349ccf8c9407a.jpg">
    </div>



<div class="svg-flex layer" data-depth="0.80" style="display: flex;">
        <h1 class="class-study-title" style="display: flex;"><h1> The Title</h1>
</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these stlyes to h1

```
h1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
```

Comment: Why does it need to be absolute to be viewable like that?

Comment: I have made those changes in the code pen and it does not appear to fix the issue.

Comment: @DavidA.French - my mistake, apply the style on h1 not 'div.svg-flex'.

Comment: Okay. For my own education, why does the h1 need to be absolute? Is that because it has no siblings?

Comment: By default it is static position and your h1 will be at the bottom of the image. To make h1 overlapping on top of the image, you need to apply absolute position, which will position it relatively to it's ancestors.

Comment: Oh. I had it set to relative though. But I just looked up the specs for relative positioning though and I have realized that relative positioning doesn't actually change the position of the object, it just changes the way it's child objects react. Thank you very much Jibin!